# JSON and Database: four booleans values versus one string value. What's better?

Tags: python, json, database

I'm developing a Python API. Essentially the API I'm trying to create is one similar to what a bank would use. It will retrieve data from my database and sent it to my desktop application, using JSON.

I'm unsure wheter:

**Option 1**

```
{
    "is_current": false,
    "is_savings": true,
    "is_credit_card": false,
    "is_loan": false,
}
```

has any advantages/disadvantages compared to:

**Option 2**

```
{
    "account_type": "savings"
}
```

I obviously see that the Option 2 requires less data transfer, so may load quicker, but for the current state of my application, "super fast" loading times are not a priority (although it may be in the distant future).

Also, what's the best way to store this in a database so I can efficiently query it?

I've tried search the site and can't seem to find anything that matches my problem.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If those four types are mutually exclusive, you should definitely only have one `account_type` field – it’s more restrictive. You might store it in your database as an `ENUM`.

Comment: @Ryan, thank you! These types are indeed mutually exclusive. Thank's for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

If no two of the four types of the account can be simultaneously true, it would be better to store as a single string. I couple of advantages of storing a single string is

- If there are any new types of accounts, you can visualize them with relative ease (without changing through hardcoded field validation in the front end)
- Storing a single field in a database will make the table less sparse, and it will also make it possible to add new types of accounts without adding whole columns to your schema

Disadvantages are that you cannot show any account that may have both loan and credit_card properties. If the context doesn't call for that, then it shouldn't be an issue.